# Playing streaming music stops when a new song starts using audio html5 tag in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, mp3, playback, html5-audio, ogg

I have setup an IceCast2 server which is capable of streaming ogg or mp3, both at 192 kbps.

In the html I use:

```
<audio controls autoplay>
    <source src="http://site.com:8000/mount1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="http://site.com:8000/mount2.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

But in Chrome 22 / Firefox 13 every time a new song begins, the player stops playback. In IE10 it continues playing without any problem. I'm thinking this might have something to do with the fact that Chrome and Firefox use the ogg source while IE uses mp3. It seems there is also a problem with Opera 12 when playing 192 kbps (music is heard saccadated), I switched to 128 and then it worked fluently.

Anyone know a fix for this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you looking into an event listener that waits for 'ended'
This is quite useful: [html5 audio the state of play](http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/#events),

You could always trigger the next track once the first track has finished

Comment: thanks for the link, this is very nice: http://jplayer.org/HTML5.Media.Event.Inspector/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting this as a temporary hack until someone gives a better answer.

In Chrome `MEDIA_ERR_DECODE` is thrown when the playback stops, while in Firefox it just stops without any error.

I changed the `src` to `currentSrc` and then called `play()` in `onerror` and `onended` event, but the sound is sometimes interrupted before resuming play. There must be a better way.

```
/* jQuery - run on document ready */
$(function ()
{
    var audioElement = $('#audioPlayer')[0];

    audioElement.onended = audioElement.onerror = function()
    {
        audioElement.src = audioElement.currentSrc;
        audioElement.play();
    };
});
```

Comment: Răzvan: did you ever find out why your streams do this?  I am having the same problem, and I would think that if the problem was in .ogg streams in general, it would be better documented than the two SO questions I've found.

Comment: @Dmitri: I didn't find out anything new. I am assuming it has to do with what was implemented regarding html5 audio in those browsers it doesn't work in.

Comment: this hacked saved me. I've been figuring out how to fix in Chrome. Was looking for flash based player but most not working.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to do so much thing as mentioned above ^ the only problem that i see in your code is that u just wrote auto play. You'll have to make it autoplay=true;